# Bosto (Nuvoton) touchpad xinput setup

Tags: usb, touchpad, libinput

I've purchased Bosto touchpad ([like this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjXvdS0u6j5AhWUv4sKHQmvBGY4FBAWegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alibaba.com%2Fproduct-detail%2FCustom-Trackpad-BOSTO-magic-touch-pad_1600377205564.html&usg=AOvVaw0CyUjkCaPMoB5hDlH7n803)), plugged it into my notebook and it worked fine. But when I plugged device into my desktop, touchpad is not working.

OS is the same on both devices: Ubuntu 20.04. On desktop I see device in lsusb, but not in xinput list. Device just don't get recognized as input device.

On notebook:

```
❯ sudo xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Nuvoton Touchpad                          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Nuvoton                                   id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

But on desktop Nuvoton entry is missing.

Any ideas how to detect configuration diff or fix it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after updating kernel to 5.15. Device now present in xinput list, but still not working. Futher investigation in [Xserver doesn't receive events from touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421798/xserver-doesnt-receive-events-from-touchpad)