# Xserver doesn't receive events from touchpad

Tags: touchpad, xserver, libinput

Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.15.0-43-generic.
Touchpad detected by xinput:

```
$ sudo xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

evtest shows that device produces events

```
$ sudo evtest /dev/input/event23
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x5ac product 0x265 version 0x110
Input device name: "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER)
    Event code 328 (BTN_TOOL_QUINTTAP)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP)
    Event code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP)
    Event code 335 (BTN_TOOL_QUADTAP)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value      0
      Min    -3678
      Max     3934
      Resolution      47
..............
Event: time 1659540389.373966, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1659540389.393961, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 2086
Event: time 1659540389.393961, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 2872
Event: time 1659540389.393961, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1659540389.413961, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 2050
Event: time 1659540389.413961, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 2916
Event: time 1659540389.413961, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1659540389.434967, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 2072
Event: time 1659540389.434967, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 2940
Event: time 1659540389.434967, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1659540389.455013, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1659540389.455013, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1659540389.470993, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 40 (ABS_MISC), value 0
Event: time 1659540389.470993, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 0
Event: time 1659540389.470993, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 0
Event: time 1659540389.470993, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

But xev shown nothing, and mouse pointer is not moved.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found that the solution is simply to install the module `psmouse` in the desktop.

`sudo modprobe psmouse`

Comment: This module is used by default. So it is unclear why this can help.